# Nextjs 404 when trying to view post

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js

I used all of the code from this tutorial ([link](https://www.djamware.com/post/5bc50ea680aca7466989441d/reactjs-firebase-tutorial-building-firestore-crud-web-application#ch6)) for a nextjs app with a custom server, and it works, but only partially, I can add stuff but when I click on some of the content it shows a 404 error. Works perfectly with CRA so my guess is that I need to do something in **server.js** perhaps or take a different approach with routing? I tried this:

```
<Link href={`/show?=${board.key}`}>{board.title}</Link>
```

but then an error pops up saying

> typeerror: cannot read property 'params' of undefined.

Any idea how I can  make this code work with nextjs? I'm so desperate, this is my 4th day trying to get it to work.

Comment: please add the code you have to the question because without it it is impossible to tell that you are doing wrong way.

Comment: here: https://gitlab.com/vidann1/crud

Answer (score 0):

Define all routes in **server.js**. In package.json file replace **"dev": "next"** with **"dev": "node server.js"**

```
static async getInitialProps(ctx) {
   const {query} = ctx;
   return query;
}

constructor(props){
   super(props);
   console.log(props);
}
```

Check props you will get an id from that.

Comment: i still get the "TypeError: Cannot read property 'params' of undefined" error on   const ref = firebase.firestore().collection('tracklist').doc(this.match.params.id);

Comment: You did not take id like `this.props.match.params.id` this. You have to use `static async getInitialProps(ctx)` of next js and return id from that as a new props and used that id accordingly. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Yes that will not work because first you have to get id by using `static async getInitialProps(ctx)` this. Please check my answer.

Comment: If you use custom server with nextjs then don't use `<Link>` for routing.

Comment: I got it working by using static async getInitialProps({ req, query, params }), then access id by this.props.params.id

Comment: Did you get it?